# Executing Powershell from qmake hangs indefinitely

Tags: windows, powershell, qmake

I am trying to execute a Powershell command from within qmake. A simplified `.pro` file looks like this:

```
$$system(powershell -NonInteractive -Command \"[long]((date).touniversaltime()-[datetime]'1970-01-01').totalmilliseconds\")
```

However, running qmake with this file or opening it in QtCreator will create a `powershell.exe` process which hangs indefinitely. Running Powershell from the command line works without problems, the command prints the expected timestamp and exits immediately.

What could be causing this hang and how to resolve it?

Tested on Windows 7 x64 with Powershell version 2.0 and qmake version 3.1 / Qt 5.9.8.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the quote.
The possible command is:

```
$$system(powershell -Command Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm")
```